# Setting up Twitter intent button, tweet shows 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I am setting up a Twitter intent button on my webpage but no matter what I set the text portion to I always get 'null' or 'undefined'

Here is a link to my codepen: http://codepen.io/JonLangel/pen/kXdmqP?editors=0010

It's vulgar so NSFW.

Here is the HTML for the twitter button:

```
        <div id="twitter-button">
          <a class="twitter-share-button" id="twitter" href="#"
            role="button" target="_blank" data-size="large">Tweet</a>
        </div>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
    var my_spreadsheet = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s-X822Oiga0j0eHC8PvegRo6W8GGC0a28nVgnvSsOqo/pubhtml';

    var sheet_data;

    function init() {
      Tabletop.init( { 
        key: my_spreadsheet, 
        callback: saveData,
        simpleSheet: true
      });
    }
    function saveData(data, tabletop) {
      sheet_data = data; 
    }

    var newQuote = function(newQuote) {
        var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sheet_data.length));
        $("#advice").html(sheet_data[randNum].Advice).addClass('animated zoomIn').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
  $(this).removeClass();
             });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

      init();

      $('.container-fluid').click(function(){
        newQuote();


      $('#twitter').attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + newQuote.randNum);
    }); 
    });
```